# Error code : REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG

Tags: webservices, error, upsert

I have an application which call a Salesforce web service to upsert data into it but since yersterday, I get errors and I don't know why because it workded since a lot of times.

These are logs :

```
2015-08-04 12:03:02,672 ERROR [Piece_jointeUpsertProcess] client.PartnerClient processResult (PartnerClient.java:432) - Errors were found on item112
2015-08-04 12:03:02,672 ERROR [Piece_jointeUpsertProcess] client.PartnerClient processResult (PartnerClient.java:434) - Error code is:REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG
2015-08-04 12:03:02,672 ERROR [Piece_jointeUpsertProcess] client.PartnerClient processResult (PartnerClient.java:435) - Error message:Your request was running for too long, and has been stopped.
```

And :

```
2015-08-04 12:20:40,145 ERROR [Piece_jointe2UpsertProcess] client.PartnerClient runOperation (PartnerClient.java:332) - Error while calling web service operation: upsert, error was: 
[UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION'
 exceptionMessage='An unexpected error occurred.'
```

I read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm) and for the first error, it says the request has taken too long to be proceded.

That means there was a timeout?

And for the second error, there is no description in logs, just 'UNKNOW_EXCEPTION'.

Unfortunately, I don't know what is upsert in Salesforce.com but I guess the error is the data?

Regards
Aurélien

Comment: If you go to Salesforce org where web service is running, then turn on debug monitoring for the user that establishes the session from your client, you can see what is taking so long (or at least some clues)

Comment: @Aurelien laval. upsert is Insert+Update. If there is no record in the object it will Insert if there is a record it will update.

Comment: @Tamil : Thank you, I know what is upsert and it should be works without error?

Comment: @crop1645 : I turnes in debug monitoriing for the user and no logs after the web service was runned, strange..

Comment: really?  did you verify that the 'running user' actually logged in by going to the User record detail page in SFDC and looking at Login History?